# Column not found laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'books.id' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `books` where `books`.`id` =
>   98745632564 limit 1)

when I pass id value as id. I have column name bookID in my database but in the above error it is comparing books.id = 98745632564. I could not understand where book.id is coming from.

```
public function showBook($id){
   $book = Book::findOrFail($id);
   return $book;
}
```

The code works perfectly fine when I pass id value with the query as follows

```
public function showBook($id){
    $book = Book::where('bookID', $id)->find();
    return $book;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'bookID';
```

in your `Book` model to make:

```
$book = Book::findOrFail($id);
```

version work.

Methods `find` or `findOrFail` are using primary key and this is by default set to `id`, so if you have any custom primary key, you should set it in your Eloquent model.