# Laravel 5.4 - Change the id use in login

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, authentication

During authentification it use the wrong id so I have this error :

> **SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Field 'id' unknown in where clause (SQL: select * from "acteur" where "id" = 22 limit 1**

The right id is : `id_biodiv_acteur`. And the model for the table `acteur` is `User.php`

So I made these change :

In `Authenticable`, `User`, `LoginController` I did

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id_biodiv_acteur';
```

In `GenericUser` I did this :

```
public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return 'id_biodiv_acteur';
}
```

But it's not working. 
If in the table of my database I put `id` instead of `id_biodiv_acteur` it work, but I want to keep the right id.

Ask me if you need to see some code.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you post your actual login method? I mean if you are using attempt method to try to login

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478429/column-not-found-laravel-5-4?#answer-43479403). May be it helps

Comment: protected $guarded = ['id_biodiv_acteur']; add in User.php and try.

Comment: Bikash, i use the login method generate by Laravel, but maybe you need my model, controller or something ?

Comment: AddWeb, it's the same problem with your fix

Comment: Do you have the `$primaryKey` set in your `User` model as well?

Comment: Bhavik, the question speak about a find method but i don't know how to use it with the login method which is really (for me) more complicated

Comment: Yes, my `$primaryKey` is also set in `User`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 - Where to change the id for login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842880/laravel-5-4-where-to-change-the-id-for-login)

Comment: yes it is the same, but nobody answer me on the other question and it is really urgent

Comment: Do you have any sort of caching enabled e.g. OPcache?

Comment: How can i know that ? I tried a `config:clear` to be sure, but it doesn't fix my problem (And i am on a private mode on firefox)